# If $Z$ is a standard normal random variable and $g(z)$ is differentiable, show that $\Bbb{E}[g'(z)]=\Bbb{E}[Zg(z)]$

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, expectation

I am looking for help proving this proposition:

"If $Z$ is a standard normal random variable and $g(z)$ is differentiable, then $\mathbb{E}[g'(Z)]=\mathbb{E}[Zg(Z)]$"

I have tried evaluating $\mathbb{E}[g'(Z)]$ using integration by parts as follows.
$$\mathbb{E}[g'(z)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{g'(z)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty{g'(z)}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$$
Let $u=e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$ and $dv=g'(z)dz$. Now,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}g(z)\Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zg(z)e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$$
Interestingly the second half of this equation is equal to $\mathbb{E}[Zg(Z)]$. I am not sure how to show that the first half of the above equation equals zero and is thus equal to $\mathbb{E}[Zg(Z)]$. I am also not sure how to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[Zg(Z)]$ as to yield the same equation, so it seems I have hit a dead end. I would like some help finishing this proof. Preferably, I want to know the simplest method.

Comment: Incidentally, I think you (or people clicking on this question) may be interested in this: https://theorydish.blog/2017/10/26/a-glimpse-at-steins-method-in-memory-of-charles-stein/

Comment: I think it is important to require here that $zg\in L^1(e^{-z^2/2}\,dz)$. Then it follows that the evaluation at $\pm\infty$ is zero.

Comment: (for indexing) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289497/why-has-the-stein-operator-for-normal-approximations-the-form-mathcal-afx?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208348/stein-equation-proof